# Как восстановить загрузчик Windows 10 (установка на SSD M.2)?

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, ssd

Первый раз в жизни я так долго вожусь с установкой Windows.
Что делал:

Выдернул все диски с стемника кроме Samsung 970 Evo series 250GB M.2 PCIe 3.0 x4 V-NAND TLC (MZ-V7E250BW)
Моя материнка MSI Z170A-G43 Plus (MS-7970)

Windows при установке разметил диск , вроде все шло как всегда , далее перезагрука и выдало мне:

> b1initializelibrary failed 0xc000000e

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я так понял что ошибка эта связана с загрузчиком , я попытался его восстановить , но безрезультатно , может опыта не хватает. Сперва стандартными Windows средствами, затем fixmbr , fixboot (фиксбот выдал отказано в доступе) , гугление дало понимание что походу в скрытом разделе вообще нет загрузочных файлов
далее сделал diskpart list disk и тут я не понял совсем нечего,

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

видно только сам диск и флешку , почему на диске нет доп разделов совсем не ясно, зашел еще раз в установку Windows, там так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите что сделать, я уже не знаю...

Вот еще фото BIOS на всякий случай стоит UEFI

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А в `legacy mode` пашет?

Comment: сбросил настройки биоса , обновил биос (там очень много нововведений по М2 было), поставил Legacy+UEFI , все встало нормально

Answer (score 2):

сбросил настройки биоса , обновил биос (там очень много нововведений по М2 было), поставил Legacy+UEFI , все встало нормально